# could not run java program with JDBC to connect postgres?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

postgres is running at local host.

I am trying to get connected with db named sample from my java program.

And i placed my java program (JDBCExample.java)to connect db and jdbc driver in the same directory.

Now i execute the command

```
postgresconnection$ java -cp postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3.jar JDBCExample
```

Error: Could not find or load main class JDBCExample

How to fix this.

Comment: This is a basic "how do I run a java program" question.  The solution in this case is to get the classpath right.  Read the question I linked to for a full explanation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
postgresconnection$ java -cp .:postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3.jar JDBCExample
```

Basically, you need to set the current dir in the classpath, java doesn't add it automatically.

Comment: Probably the right solution ... but it doesn't explain why.

Comment: I explained it, see my updated answer. Initially, I though that It would be auto-explanatory, the "java -cp .:post..." is a good clue.